# Preg_match_all, word with randon text

Tags: php, regex

I'm in trouble with preg_match, I want to extract a div using preg_match.

Div Example: `<div class="post_message_(RANDOM NUMBER)">`

I've tried to use `<div\s+class="post_message_/\w+/"\s*>` to detect the number sequence after the keyword and fill the preg_match_all command.

But `<div\s+class="post_message_/\w+/"\s*>` is not working, anyone know how to perform this?

Regards,

Comment: Are you using `preg_match` or `preg_match_all` ? Also is it a random number of random text (including letters as well as numbers) ?

Comment: is your content of `RANDOM_NUMBER` between `()`?

Comment: if its between `()`, you are missing to include `()` in your regex..use `<div\s+class="post_message_\(\w+\)"\s*>`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want a random number (and not random text of numbers and letters) then this will catch the `123456`:

```
$re = "/<div\\s+class=\"post_message_([\\d]+)\"\\s*>/"; 
$str = "<div class=\"post_message_123456\">"; 

preg_match($re, $str, $matches);
```